# Problems with my first project of renaming file names

Tags: python, windows, rename, fnmatch

I recently started with python since I want to become better in geophysics and processing data.

I began with a little sideproject to rename the monthly extract files of my bank account. They have a silly order of date and name and I just want to order them by date.

One of the file names would be *AZG149882014_001_20170129*.

The last 8 symbols are the date, but in a very unintuitive order, where my winodws system cannot order them properly.

So far the file name changes into *20170129* but does not change the order of the date.

It also does display the year for *yy* at all. I am a little bit lost. I know that I have to put this also into the replace function, but it won't work with the ways I tried.

Could you help me out?

```
import os, fnmatch

file_path = 'censored path'

files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.pdf')




for file_name in files_to_rename:  
    yy = file_name[-4:-1]
    mm = file_name[-6:-4]
    dd = file_name[-8:-6]
    date=dd + '.' + mm + '.'+ yy
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '*2017*'):                
        new_name = os.rename(file_path + file_name, file_path + file_name.replace(file_name[0:17], ''))
        new_name=str(new_name)+str(date)
        print(new_name)
```

Comment: will it work that if i hardcode only the year because assuming that the year won't become a 5 character string untill the year 10,000 so can i just index the year as 4 characters?

Comment: and one more question if the date instead of 29 changes to 1 will it just be 1 or be 01?

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you want?**

```py
import os

def rename(path):
    path = path
    date = path.split("_")[-1] # Assuming that the date comes after underscores
    yy, mm, dd = date[0:4], date[4:6], date[6:8] # Assuming that the year 10,00 will not come so fast, so considered the year as 4 character string and the month and date stays a two character string like 01, 12, 09, so on...
    
    result = yy + "." + mm + "." + dd # String Concatenation
    os.rename(path, result) # Rename the file

print(rename("DRIVE:\\User\\Folder\\AZG149882014_001_20170129"))  # Pass the location
```

**OR, a more compact and memory efficient way to do the same thing-**

```py
import os

def rename(path):
    os.rename(path, path.split("_")[-1][0:4] + "." + path.split("_")[-1][4:6] + "." + path.split("_")[-1][6:8])

rename("DRIVE:\\User\\Folder\\AZG149882014_001_20170129")
```

You can expand on this idea and use `FOR LOOPS` to rename multiple files together although it might more time.

Hope so it helps!
Happy Coding